# Using diff to compare a file with a variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, diff

In diff command am getting following error. Kindly assist how can I specify I want to see difference between file `ran` and variable `current_unavail`:

```
$ current_unavail=ranjith
$ cat /tmp/ran
ranjith
$ test=$(cat /tmp/ran)
```

**error which I am getting**

```
$ diff `$current_unavail` `$test`
diff: missing operand after `diff'
diff: Try `diff --help' for more information.
```

Comment: What are your two files? I can only see one file `/tmp/ran`. `$current_unavail` is a variable, not a file. Are you trying to compare the contents of a variable with the contents of a file? Please [edit] your question to make it clear.

Comment: yes tom... I am comparing file & variable. file which already stored in /tmp . variable which generate at time of script runs. could you pls assist. if you have any further query kindly reply.

Answer (score 6):

You're using the wrong kind of quotes. Assuming that `$current_unavail` and `$test` are two shell variables, each containing the name of a file, you should be doing this:

```
diff "$current_unavail" "$test"
```

Backticks `` ` `` are used for command substitutions (like `` a=`cmd` ``), although the preferred syntax is `a=$(cmd)`.

---

To compare a **file** `/tmp/ran` with a **variable** `$current_unavail`, you can do this:

```
diff /tmp/ran <(echo "$current_unavail")
```

`diff` works with file descriptors, not variables. But in bash you can use a [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution) `<( ... )` to create a temporary file descriptor from the result of executing a command.

Comment: Is it possible to compare two variables in bash ?

Comment: Is it possible to compare two variables in bash ?  I just tried with this below mention  current_unavail=$(apple)  & last_unavail=$(apple) **result=$(diff <(echo -e "$current_unavail") <(echo -e "$last_unavail"))**  it works good. once enter I put into the script the below error display **unavail_cn.sh: command substitution: line 9: `diff <(echo -e "$current_unavail") <(echo -e "$last_unavail"))'**